# How to include maatwebsite in custom PHP application?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, customization

I'm trying to use maatwebsite in my custom PHP application because of my experience using this in Laravel. The code is as follows:

```
<?php

include('C:\xampp\htdocs\fileconvert\vendor\autoload.php');

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel AS Excel;

Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {

    $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {

        $sheet->fromArray(array(
            array('data1', 'data2'),
            array('data3', 'data4')
        ));

    });

})->store('xls');
```

But it's throwing my following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileconvert\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php:234 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fileconvert\test2.php(18): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('create', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fileconvert\test2.php(18): Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::create('Filename', Object(Closure)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileconvert\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 234

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you would want to use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel rather than the laravel version

Comment: As @SariYono said, you can't use Laravel components outside of Laravel (without some hacking at least) so use phpoffice/phpexcel instead (that's the library used by maatwebsite's package.